# Can I install Python, Django and other packages on a USB device and and run a server from this USB?

Tags: python, django

I would like to have a Django server on a Windows machine which is not connected to Internet.

For that, would it be possible to install, from another Windows machine connected to Internet, Python, PyCharm, Django and other packages to a USB device that I will then connect to the other Windows machine in order to start the application ?

Would it work without problems ?
Thanks !

-

Comment: Yes,  You can use packages like pyinstaller to create a standalone executable that contains all the packages you need.

Comment: Since you mentioned PyCharm: PyCharm is an IDE, you don't need it to run your Python software.